# Auto mounting external hard disk using fstab gives all read write permission to it

Tags: mount

This is the deal:

I had been using my Hard disk for quite a while and recently I used fstab to mount it automatically in `/media/kevin/toshiba`.

Now, whenever it is mounted, its permission becomes `drwxrwxrwx`. Plugging-in the hard disk in another computer shows the default permission which is obviously not the above.

How do I mount the h with the default permissions retained.

**Edit 1:**

This is my `/etc/fstab` entry :

```
# <file system>         <mount point>               <type>  <options>     <dump> <pass>
UUID=8C3669123668FE98   /media/kevin/kevin-toshiba  ntfs    defaults        0       0
```

I tried this too :

```
# <file system>         <mount point>              <type>  <options>                             <dump> <pass>
UUID=8C3669123668FE98   /media/kevin/kevin-toshiba  ntfs   nls=iso8859-1,permissions,users,auto    0     0
```

Comment: What you written in fstab?

Comment: @alb3rtano0012 Add additional details to the question.

Comment: When mounting with the permissions option, you would then use chown and chmod to change ownership and permissions to what you desire. chown/chmod only need be run once possible as root.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that a much easier way to auto-mount drives is to put your mount commands in /etc/rc.local .  I had all sorts of headaches with using fstab so that's what I do now.  /etc/rc.local is a bash script that is executed by root at startup.  Just create the folder you want the drive to be mounted in and then add your mount command anywhere above the "exit" line in /etc/rc.local, then reboot.

Here's what mine looks like.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

#Mounts Storage
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/Storage

exit 0
```

Comment: That will only mount drives present at boot, otherwise you have to call the script. In addition "/dev/sdb1" is arbitrary and the partition can change, better to use UUID. Last, that does not answer the question as it does not set permissions on the OP ntfs partition.